# Zero Knowlege/Trust Architecture with shared encryption keys (maybe Shamir's secret sharing?)

Tags: secret-sharing, zero-knowledge

I'm working on an idea for a backend data store that stores encrypted data that is zero knowledge/trust, however is shareable to a number of parties.  I don't want the backend service to know anything about the data or manage keys, so if the data was ever compromised then it would be meaningless to an attacker.  Therefore, the client would have to do all the work and be the trusted device.

The catch is that I want to be able to share the encrypted data with multiple 3rd party services on demand if the user/client gives them permission for parts of the data.

I'm thinking this could be some sort of zero knowledge/trust architecure combined with something like Shamir's secret sharing.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  Does something like this already exist or am I over thinking it?